# VBA Cut Paste Transpose - Repeat

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, transpose

I am looking to write a script so I can put a button on an evaluation form that will pull a range (for example: name, title, income) from another file or worksheet. Each time the macro button is pressed, the data copied or cut needs to come from the next row in the source table and overwrite the data on the evaluation form worksheet. The data copied also needs to be transposed.

So far, this modified script is the closest I've come. I wrote a separate Macro that pulls the data from the source file and puts it in a new sheet in the evaluation workbook. This script cuts and pastes that list in the same sheet. I'm not sure if it's the with statement that is preventing me from modifying the destination range to another sheet.

```
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Report.xlsx").Worksheets("Injury")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("HR TEST.xlsm").Worksheets("Evaluation")
    
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      
    '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
    'Offset property moves down 1 row
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    ' New content from copy paste transpose
With wsCopy
        
    
    '3. Clear contents of existing data range
    wsDest.Range("A2:G" & lDestLastRow).ClearContents

    '4. Copy & Paste Data
    wsCopy.Range("A2:G2").Copy
    wsDest.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
```

Comment: `.Range` means it refers to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")` because of the dot.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the range at the bottom of the code. If I change the .Range(strPasteAddress) to a different sheet will that resolve the issue?

Comment: Could you share the screenshots of the worksheets (the expected result for the destination)? Also, add the first code since it is unclear why you would need to copy the data twice (add an explanation).

Comment: I had it copied twice because I was having trouble referencing it from the original source file. I updated the code and was able to pull the data from the source file and paste it transposed in the specified area. The issue now is getting it to loop to the next row in the source file to copy and paste.